# How to pass a symbol of a condition of a function to a macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm trying to pass a symbol of a condition of a function to a macro, and see the result:

```
(defmacro macro-test-1 (form condition)
  `(handler-case (funcall ,form)
     (,condition (c)
       (declare (ignore c))
       (format t "~a" 'why?))))

(macro-test-1 #'(lambda () (error 'simple-type-error)) division-by-zero)
;; OK, I get the simple-type-error as expected.

(defun test-1 (condition)
  (macro-test-1 #'(lambda () (error 'simple-type-error)) condition))
; in: DEFUN TEST-1
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA TEST-1
;         (CONDITION)
;       (BLOCK TEST-1
;         (MACRO-TEST-1 #'(LAMBDA () (ERROR 'SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR)) CONDITION)))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable CONDITION is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
TEST-1
;; what happened?

(test-1 'division-by-zero)
WHY?
NIL
;; what happened?
```

I'm pretty confused by what's going on, I've been trying to figure it out for a long time, I hope I'm missing something silly.

> up 1

It is as I imagined, silly error, now I realized what I was trying to do, the macro will be expanded at compile time, and the argument I pass to the function at runtime, so the macro will not receive the condition argument correctly. So I see two possibilities of solving this, turning macro-test-1 into a function or turning test-1 into a macro.

Actually I tested here, changing to function still not working:

```
CL-USER> (defun macro-test-1 (form condition)
  (handler-case (funcall form)
     (condition (c)
       (declare (ignore c))
       (format t "~a" 'why?))))

; in: DEFUN MACRO-TEST-1
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA MACRO-TEST-1
;         (FORM CONDITION)
;       (BLOCK MACRO-TEST-1
;         (HANDLER-CASE (FUNCALL FORM)
;                       (CONDITION (C) (DECLARE #) (FORMAT T "~a" 'WHY?)))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable CONDITION is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::MACRO-TEST-1 in DEFUN

CL-USER> (macro-test-1 #'(lambda () (error 'simple-type-error)) 'division-by-zero)
WHY?
NIL
```

However when you redefine macro-test-1 as a macro, and redefine test-1 as a macro:

```
CL-USER> (defmacro test-1 (condition)
  `(macro-test-1 #'(lambda () (error 'simple-type-error)) ,condition))
TEST-1

 CL-USER> (test-1 division-by-zero)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR {1001BB8FF3}>.
```

I'm still not sure why the function does not work, the evaluation rule is not to evaluate all arguments and then pass to the body of the function the evaluated arguments? Because it does not work?

> up 2

I understand that the `handler-case`  does not work because you need to know the errors at compile time, and passing `condition` as a runtime function argument would not be able to know the compile-time error, so it does not work. And I stress this single reason, and not because macros occur has compile time, by a question I noted below which led me to this whole mess, and made me believe it is possible to pass `condition` by a function. I can do this:

```
(defmacro macro-test-1 (fn value)
`(funcall ,fn ,value 1))

(macro-test-1 #'= 1)
;; => T it is OK

(defun test-1 (fn value)
(macro-test-1 fn value))

(test-1 #'= 1)
;; => why it is OK?
```

The above code works, even though I pass the arguments to the function at runtime, why does it work? if the macro is expanded at compile time, why is it working when I call `test-1`? or are macros not always expanded at compile time? What am I missing here?

> up 3

I decided to go deeper, and tried:

```
(defmacro macro-test-1 (fn value)
`(,fn ,value 1))

(macro-test-1 = 1)
;; => T it is OK

(defun test-1 (fn value)
  (macro-test-1 fn value))
; in: DEFUN TEST-1                      
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA TEST-1       
;         (FN VALUE)                    
;       (BLOCK TEST-1 (MACRO-TEST-1 FN VALUE)))
;                                       
; caught STYLE-WARNING:                 
;   The variable FN is defined but never used.
; in: DEFUN TEST-1                      
;     (MACRO-TEST-1 FN VALUE)           
; ==>                                   
;   (FN VALUE 1)                        
;                                       
; caught STYLE-WARNING:                 
;   undefined function: FN              
;                                       
; compilation unit finished             
;   Undefined function:                 
;     FN                                
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions   
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::TEST-1 in DEFUN
TEST-1
```

Yes I know that if I try as shown below, it will not exit as expected:

```
(test-1 '= 1)
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION FN {1004575323}>. ;
```

But I wanted to find a way to make it work, so I tried, until I could, by resetting macro-test-1 to:

```
(defmacro macro-test-1 (fn value)
  `(eval (,fn ,value 1)))
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::MACRO-TEST-1 in DEFMACRO
MACRO-TEST-1
(defun test-1 (fn value)
  (macro-test-1 fn value))
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::TEST-1 in DEFUN
TEST-1

(test-1 '= 1)
T
```

Of course this would only work in `handler-case` or `case`, if I redefined its macros, which I believe should not be a good practice, nor do I need it, but I like to go where it does not, well, then, I learn erring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are code transformation. Thus the expansion can happen as early as when you evaluate a `defun`. eg.

```
(defun test-1 (condition)
  (macro-test-1 #'(lambda () (error 'simple-type-error)) condition))

;; becomes this 

(defun test-1 (condition)
  (handler-case (funcall #'(lambda nil (error 'simple-type-error)))
    (condition (c) 
      (declare (ignore c)) (format t "~a" 'why?)))
```

Now just lets say you want to have handler-case check for `simple-type-error`. You'll write it like this:

```
  (handler-case expression
    (simple-type-error () 
      (format t "~a" 'why?)))
```

not

```
  (handler-case expression
    ('simple-type-error () 
      (format t "~a" 'why?)))
```

Eg. `handler-case` is syntax and that place is can not have a variable be evaluated to some error, but must be a type specifier and that is probably handled compile time by the system. This is the reason you get that `condition` is never used since your `handler-case` checks for a type called `condition`, not what you sent as the `condition` argument.

Making `test-1` a macro actually passes `division-by-zero` as the symbol to `macro-test-1` and the result is this:

```
(handler-case (funcall #'(lambda nil (error 'simple-type-error)))
  (division-by-zero (c) 
    (declare (ignore c)) 
    (format t "~a" 'why?)))
```

This also means the errors need to be known compile time since you cannot have a macro be passed values in variables. That is why it works so the second you want some user to input what error to act on you cannot do it with your solution.

**EDIT**

In `up2` you ask why this works:

```
(defun test-1 (fn value) 
  (macro-test-1 fn value))
```

So we'll just find out what actually gets saved:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(macro-test-1 fn value))
; ==> (funcall fn value)
; ==> t
```

Thus your function becomes this:

```
(defun test-1 (fn value) 
  (funcall fn value))
```

`handler-case` was syntax that didn't take variables or expression at the place you wanted and thats why that didn't work, but it will of course work for all functions, including `funcall`, since it evaluates all it's arguments.

To show you a different example of what does not work is `case`:

```
(defun check-something (what result default-value value)
  (case value
    (what result)
    (otherwise default-value)))
```

`case` is a macro so what actually happens. We can do `macroexpand-1` on it to see:

```
(macroexpand-1 
  '(case value
    (what result)
    (otherwise default-value))
   )
; ==> (let ((tmp value))
;       (cond ((eql tmp 'what) result) 
;             (t default-value)))
; ==> t
```

The macro expects the case values to be literals and thus quotes them so that they never get evaluated. The resulting function you clearly see `what` is never used, just as `condition` wasn't:

```
(defun check-something (what result default-value value)
  (let ((tmp value))
    (cond ((eql tmp 'what) result) 
          (t default-value))))
```

Macros are to abstract on syntax. You need to be able to write the code without the macro and rather see that this is a pattern that repeats and than add an abstraction that rewrites from your simplified version to the full version. If it cannot be done to begin with it cannot be rewritten as a macro.

Same for functions. The whole reason why we have macros is to control evaluation. A good example of something that cannot be written as a fucntion is `if`:

```
(defun my-if (predicate consequence alternative)
  (cond (predicate consequence)
        (t alternative)))

(my-if t 'true 'false)   ; ==> true    
(my-if nil 'true 'false) ; ==> false
```

But since functions always evaluates their arguments you cannot do this:

```
(defun factorial (n)
  (my-if (<= n 1)
         1
         (* n (factorial (1- n)))))
```

This will never halt since being a function all 3 arguments are always evalaued and `(* n (factorial (1- n))))` is done even when `n` is negative and it will have endless recursion. Using a macro instead would replace the `my-if` with the resulting `cond` and both `cond` and `if` does not evaluate all their arguments rather than short circuits on the one that matches truthy predicate.

You may use `macroexpand-1` to check if you code indeed is correct. You should be able to replace the input with the ourput. Is you use `macroexpand` applies the expansion until it will not expand anymore. Eg. `cond` will also be expanded to nested `if`'s.

**EDIT 2**

From `up3`:

```
(defun test-1 (fn value)
  (macro-test-1 fn value))
```

This is the same problem. The macro function gets `fn` and `value` as bindings and the result is:

```
(defun test-1 (fn value)
  (fn value))
```

This might have worked in Scheme, but in Common Lisp symbols in operator prosition is **different** from other positions. Thus when CL tries to find the function `fn` it never look any close to the variable `fn`. The only way to solve this is by using `funcall` and then you actually don't need a macro at all:

```
(defun with-1 (fn value)
  (funcall fn value 1))

(with-1 #'+ 10) ; ==> 11
```

Notice the `#'` prefix. That is short for `(function ...)` so it's really `(function +)`. `function` is a special form that takes the argument symbol and gets the value from the function namespace.

With `eval` you can do a lot of stuff, but it comes with a price. It will not be optimized and perhaps even just interpreted and it might gove you compile time errors at runtime as well as open for security risks. A good example was a online interactive ruby that just did `eval` and it worked well until someone evaluated code that deleted all the system files. `eval` is [considered harmful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu/311510) and even evil. In my professional career I have seen `eval` being used 3 times on purpose. (2 times in PHP, one in requirejs). One of those times I challenged the writer that there might be a better way to do it. Of course both `handler-case` and `case` will work with `eval` since the evaluated code would have the correct format, but you'll loose the lexical scoping. eg.

```
(let ((x 10))
  (eval '(+ x 1))); 
; *** EVAL: variable X has no value
```

You might be smart and do this:

```
(let ((x 10))
  (eval `(+ ,x 1))) ; ==> 11
```

but what if it was a list or something else not self evaluating?

```
(let ((x '(a b)))
  (eval `(cons '1 ,x)))
; *** undefined function: a
```

Thus `eval` has its chalenges as well. Keep away for other purposes than education ones.

Comment: I updated my question, see `up 2`, was what caused me the confusion.

Comment: I think I understand. I played a little more, see `up 3`.

Comment: @PerduGames I've updated the answer. Except for the `eval` which of course trumps all laws it's the same cause.

Comment: Very good, I suspected that "eval" would not be a good practice, because I come from the javascript and there "eval" opens some holes, the same ones you said. But "eval" has its safe uses.